# Get name of a resource currently loaded in TImage component - Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, inherited-resources

I've been looking around but haven't found anything specific...

I built a resoruce file containing about 100 small png images, and I load them randomly all over the app.
I then have OnClick event on every TImage component, where I do get the Sender's name (Image1, Image2 etc..) but don't know how could I get the name of an indentifier, which is currently loaded in the sender (TImage) from the resource...

Is this even possible, or would I need to store kind of a stringlist or a database containing info about which resource is used for every picture...?

The GetNamePath retrieves nothing...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TImage` component (or the Picture and Bitmap properties) doesn't store any reference to the resources loaded. So you must do this manually. Try using a dictionary (`TDictionary<TImage, Integer>`) with the references to the resource id and the TImage or you can create  new component which descends from the [`TImage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TImage) adding a new property to store the loaded resource id.

Comment: I ended up adding used image id to image tag instead, as currently I don't need it for anything else. Just wanted to know if there's any way of doing this directly... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could load the images into a `TImageList` first, then retrieve individual images from that list into each `TImage` as needed, and then use the `TImage.Tag` property to keep track of which index was retrieved.  If you use a `TPNGImageList`, you can store extra data with each image in the list, just as the original resource identifier name.

Comment: I ended up adding used image id to image tag instead, just as you suggested,, as currently I don't need it for anything else. Just wanted to know if there's any way of doing this directly... Thanks.